# No space left on device mysql

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

I have a vm instance on compute engine gcloud and mysqld server (mariadb) does not connect,
error:
waiting for someone to free some space ... (**errno: 28 "No space left on device**").
**here the log file** : [mysqld log file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10zaPn58qgNt1EhvY2upg1VAWbeMknkJFd7FR9P8vySk/edit?usp=sharing)

**I have 10 GB disk space;**

**mysqld db size is: 261M;**

I run these command through vm instance ssh to check:

$ **df -h /jet/var/mysqld**

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1         9.8G    9.3G      0   100% /

**$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1**

Disk /dev/sda1: 10 GiB,

10735321088 bytes, 20967424 sectors
Units:

sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

**strong text**
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

$ df

Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on

udev              859516       0    859516   0% /dev

tmpfs             174132    6144    167988   4% /run

/dev/sda1       10253588 9713292         0 100% /

tmpfs             870656       0    870656   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock

tmpfs             870656       0    870656   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

tmpfs             174128       0    174128   0% /run/user/1000

$ sudo du -sh /jet/prs/mysqld/data

261M    /jet/prs/mysqld/data

[ssh command and messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMlPP.jpg)

I don't know what caused the problem.

Comment: Add the output of `df -h` to your question. If `/jet` is ta 100% Used, then that is what's causing the message but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked all directories  (sudo du -sh /dir..)  and found that in the directory

 ` /var/cache/apt/archives  is full for 5.8G.`
I found many file: 

[on this link the list of all](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1km2TW-tCXdndPmp-vDhtp-0V8AKICkSu/view?usp=sharing) 

seems to be system images but I dont't understand the reason why are inside the gcloud vm instance

I deleted  all, increased disk space to 20GB, and created a cron job that cleans the directory every three months after 6.25 hours which appears to be the time gcloud updates something

Answer (score 3):

```
Filesystem Size     Used    Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1  10253588 9713292 0     100% /
```

Your root partition is full. That will stop everything on your host.

Running a database server isn't just about the size of the data, it's also about all of the things that support it: backups, log files, transaction history, indexes, etc. When / (root) fills up, it is often because log files have gotten out of control.

1. Check /var/log to see if there's anything there you can delete to free up space.
2. Make sure all of your logs are being rotated to automatically remove old files.
3. Make sure 10GB is really enough space. It looks like that's your only real partition: is that enough space to hold the operating system, the database software, data files, log files, etc.? Best practice would be to put the DB-related stuff into separate partitions, and possibly /var/log as well, just so that if something *does* grow out of control it doesn't fill up root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked all directories  (sudo du -sh /dir..)  and found that in the directory

 ` /var/cache/apt/archives  is full for 5.8G.`
I found many file: 

[on this link the list of all](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1km2TW-tCXdndPmp-vDhtp-0V8AKICkSu/view?usp=sharing) 

seems to be system images but I dont't understand the reason why are inside the gcloud vm instance

I deleted  all, increased disk space to 20GB, and created a cron job that cleans the directory every three months after 6.25 hours which appears to be the time gcloud updates something